# cpp array - Assigning constant index works while non-constant index does not work

Tags: c++

I'm trying to assign a value to array.

Type of arrayPointer is int*. The code below is minimal reproducible code.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class ExtendableArray;

class ElementRef {
private:
    ExtendableArray *intArrayRef; //pointer to the array
    int index;                    // index of this element
public:
    ElementRef(ExtendableArray &theArray, int i);
    ElementRef &operator=(int val);
    operator int() const;
};

class ExtendableArray {
private:
    int *arrayPointer; // integer array pointer
    int size;          // the size of array
public:
    ExtendableArray();
    ElementRef operator[](int i);

    friend class ElementRef;
};

int main() {
    ExtendableArray arr;
    printf("arr[1]: %d\n", (int) arr[1]);
    arr[0] = 5;
    return 0;
}


ElementRef::ElementRef(ExtendableArray &theArray, int i) {
    ExtendableArray *ref = &theArray;
    intArrayRef = ref;
    index = i;
}

ElementRef &ElementRef::operator=(int val) {
    printf("0: %d\n", intArrayRef->arrayPointer[0]);

    intArrayRef->arrayPointer[0] = 5;
    printf("0: %d\n", intArrayRef->arrayPointer[0]);
    printf("INDEX: %d\n", index);


    intArrayRef->arrayPointer[index] = 5;
}


ElementRef::operator int() const {
    return this->intArrayRef->arrayPointer[this->index];
}


ExtendableArray::ExtendableArray() {
    this->arrayPointer = new int[2]{0};
    this->size = 2;
}

ElementRef ExtendableArray::operator[](int i) {
    ElementRef ref = ElementRef(*this, i);
    return ref;
}
```

The code above crashes with

0: 0

0: 5

INDEX: 0

Process finished with exit code 4

When I attach debugger, debugger points `intArrayRef->arrayPointer[index] = 5;`

How can this happen? I mean, why does constant index works while non-constant index crashes?

Comment: what is a "resizable array" ? Please post a [mcve]

Comment: What is the type of index? How are you setting it?

Comment: btw your code and output looks fine to me, the reason your program exits with code 4 is maybe in code you didnt show

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 I added minimal reproducible code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot return statement, and it results in a crash. When I change code to return *this, it works.

Compiler show warning, but I couldn't see warnings as I pressed debug button on CLion

```cpp
ElementRef &ElementRef::operator=(int val) {
    printf("0: %d\n", intArrayRef->arrayPointer[0]);

    intArrayRef->arrayPointer[0] = 5;
    printf("0: %d\n", intArrayRef->arrayPointer[0]);
    printf("INDEX: %d\n", index);


    intArrayRef->arrayPointer[index] = 5;
    return *this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's just how arrays in c++ work, they have a constant index. You will have to use another class for your problem, i would recommend

```
std::vectory<Type T>
```

which will allow you to add elements, store them and also in comparison to c++ Lists, elements of a vector can be adressed by index which feels more like an array with variable length.

The documentation on vectors can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/cpp/standard-library/vector-class?view=vs-2019).